# Не выводятся ошибки валидации и не возвращаются поля с предыдущими данными Формы

Tags: laravel, валидация

Laravel 5.2

Как я понимаю проблема в том, что в сессию не сохраняются данные формы и текст ошибок валидации. Если я все тоже самое делаю, но без валидации данных в Контроллере, то в сесиию все отлично сохраняется.

Есть простая **вью** с формой отправки данных (через шаблонизатор **'blade'**):

```
    @if( count($errors) > 0 )
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach( $errors->all() as $error ) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        <form method="POST" action="{{  route('contact') }}">  <!-- <?//='/contact');?> Or <?//=route('contact');?> -->
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Enter E-mail">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="site">Site:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site" name="site" value="{{ old('site') }}" placeholder="Enter Site">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text_area">Text:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="text_area" name="text_area" rows="3" placeholder="Some text....."> {{ old('text_area') }} </textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>

        </div> <!--/class="col-"-->
    </div> <!--/class="row"-->
@endsection
```

Есть простой Контроллер **`ContactController.php`**

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactController extends Controller {


    public function show( Request $request, $prm=false ){

        $my_array = ['title1'=>'This variable `$title1` content', 'title2'=>'This variable `$title2` content', 'title3'=>'This variable `$title3` content']; //массив
        $my_array2 = ['one'=>array('param1'=>'This variable `param1` content', 'param2'=>'This variable `param2` content', 'param3'=>'This variable `param3` content'),
            'two'=>array('param4'=>'This variabl e `param4` content', 'param5'=>'This variable `param5` content', 'param6'=>'This variable `param6` content')
        ];

        $my_array3 = array(
            'title'=>'Contact',
            'data'=>[ 'one'=>'list 1',
                'two'=>'list 2',
                'three'=>'list 3',
                'four'=>'list 4',
                'five'=>'list 5',
            ],
            'dataI'=>['list-1','list-2','list-3','list-4','list-6','list-6'],
            'bvar'=>true,
            'script'=>"<script>alert('Hello! ++')</script>"
        );

        /** VALIDATION on Request */
        if( $request->isMethod('post') ) {
            //$request->session()->reflash();
            //$request->session()->keep(['name', 'email', 'site', 'text_area']);
            //$request->session()->reflash();
            //dump( $request->session()->all() );


            $rules = [
                'name' => 'required|max:10',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                //'site'=>'required',
                //'text_area'=>'required',
            ];

            $messages = [
                'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
            ];

            $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
                dump( $request->all() );
                dump( $request->session()->all() );
        }


        if( view()->exists('default.contact') ){
            return view('default.contact')
                ->withMydata($my_array2)
                ->withMydata2($my_array)
                ->withMydata3($my_array3);
        }
        else { abort(404); }

    }

}
```

По идее,когда валидация данных по установленным правилам успешна для кадого из перечисленных полей Формы, то код после инициализации процесса валидации (строка **$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);**) будет выполнен и я получаю dump того, что в POST и того, что будет записано в сессию. Когда валидация успешна, данные в Форме не должны оставаться, а вот когда валидация провалена, то должно генерироваться исключение и должен происходить редирект на предыдущую страницу, а данные, сохраняться в сессии и, благодаря указанной конструкции в вьюхе
**value="{{ old('name') }}"** отображаться в полях. Но у меня этого не происходит.
Если я верно ввожу данные в форму, чтобы валидация была успешна, - я вижу распечатку POST, что значит, валидация таки успешно прошла (и правила то действуют, указанные в Контролллере), но вот когда я ввожу не верные для валидирования данные, чтоб провалить ее, то и сохраненных данных в полях я не вижу, что как я понимаю, должно быть автоматически в этом механизме валидации заложено.
Скажу также, что разрешение на запись **flash()-данных**, да и вообще запись в сессию, как я понимаю, я тоже прописал в **`/app/Http/Kernel.php`**

```
    /**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
];
```

При этом, как я говорил, если я не буду в контроллере проводить валидацию данных, и установлю **$request->flash();** чтобы данные из POST записывались в сессию одноразово, то они записываются и в Форме остаются, т.е. тут все работает корректно.
Но используя валидацию, я эту строку **$request->flash();** удаляю, т.к. судя по документации механизм валидации сам это делает и это писать не нужно.
Кто подскажет, что я забыл прописать или сделал не верно, что у меня не работает валидация совместно с записью в сессию и отображением после провала валидации и соответственно редиректа, старых значений в input. И ошибок валидации тоже нет, хотя во вьюхе я их тоже указал.

```
    @if( count($errors) > 0 )
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach( $errors->all() as $error ) <li>{{ $error }}</li> @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

P/S: Как я могу видеть то валидация отрабатывает и ее правила действуют, 
но я не вижу отображения ошибок валидации, когда она не пройдена и данных в полях  input при заполнении Формы при редиректе обратно.

Comment: Как все таки разрешился этот вопрос. У меня точно такая же проблема!

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере и вью все правильно. Вы не предоставили ваш routes.php, но подозреваю, что `ContactController@show` у вас обрабатывается группой middlewares `web`:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // ваши роуты
});
```

Если это так, то переместите StartSession и ShareErrorsFromSession в группу роутов web:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ],
];
```

Только не удаляйте те, которые там уже есть. Посмотрите пример в [стартовом проекте](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.2/app/Http/Kernel.php).